# Click submit button twice for form to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, button

I have a problem with posting the user input from the following code. The information gets posted only after the submit button has been clicked twice. Please take a look at my code and tell me if there is anything I need to change.

```
<script>
function validate(form) {
    fail = validateName(form.name.value)
    fail += validateEmail(form.email.value)
    fail += validateCity(form.city.value)
    if (fail == "") {
        $(function () {
            $('#submitbtn').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).closest('form'),
                    action = form.attr('action');
                $.post(action, form.serialize(), function (data) {
                    $('#errors').html("You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter.");
                })
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = fail;
    }
    return false
}
function validateName(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No name was entered.<br/>"
    else if (field.length < 3) return "Please enter a valid name.<br/>"
    else if (!/[a-zA-Z ]/.test(field)) return "Name can only have alphabetical characters.<br/>"
    return ""
}

function validateEmail(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No email was entered.<br/>"
    else if (!((field.indexOf(".") > 0) && (field.indexOf("@") > 0)) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field)) return "The email address is invalid.<br/>"
    return ""
}

function validateCity(field) {
    if (field == "") return "No city was entered.<br/>"
    else if (field.length < 3) return "Please enter a valid city.<br/>"
    else if (!/[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(field)) return "City can only have alphabetical characters.<br/>"
    return ""
}
            
</script>


</head>

<body id="body-results-page">
    <div class="modalDialog" id="openModal">
        <div>
            <a class="close" href="#close" title="Close">X</a>
            
     <h2>Newsletter Sign-Up</h2>      

  <form action="" name="subscribe1" id="subscribe1" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
<div id="errors"></div>
<input name="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*$" title="Please enter only alphabetic characters" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name"/>


<input name="email" required id="email" type="email" title="Please enter your email address" placeholder="Your email address"/>

<input name="city" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*$" title="Please enter only alphabetic characters" id="city" placeholder="Your city"/>

<div id="buttons">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset"/>
            
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" value="Submit this!">Subscribe Now!</button>
            
            <br style="clear:both;">
        </div>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="subscribe1">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling function `validate(form)` on submit and adding submit handler to button after it but not calling it .

Solution - Call submit handler after attaching click submit handler to button.

```
$('#submitbtn').click();
```

Like this

```
if (fail == "") {
    $(function () {
        $('#submitbtn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest('form'),
                action = form.attr('action');
            $.post(action, form.serialize(), function (data) {
                $('#errors').html("You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter.");
            })
        }).click();
    });
}
```

or

Better don't attach submit handler just run the AJAX request direct if condition is true .

like this

```
if (fail == "") {
        action = $(form).attr('action');
    $.post(action, $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
        $('#errors').html("You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter.");
    })
}
```

Comment: What changes should i make to my code? I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind submit handler. As you are performing validation of in your `validate(form)` function.

So instead of

```
if (fail == "") {
    $(function () {
        $('#submitbtn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest('form'),
                action = form.attr('action');
            $.post(action, form.serialize(), function (data) {
                $('#errors').html("You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter.");
            })
        });
    });
}
```

Just use

```
if (fail == "") {
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        action = form.attr('action');
    $.post(action, form.serialize(), function (data) {
        $('#errors').html("You have been successfully subscribed to our newsletter.");
    })
}
```